# What is Microsoft Graph API endpoints pattern?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to programmatically consume Microsoft Graph API. By parsing the meta data from Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata), I can understand the data models and the relationship between these data models. But there are no endpoints information available in the metadata. For example, If I want to List messages. How would I know which endpoint I should send request to? From the metadata, I can only know we have Users model which contains messages model as a NavigationProperty, Then If the Microsoft Graph API follow some pattern to come up each endpoints, which I guess they do, then I can programmatically calculate the endpoints as /users/identifier/messages. Is this pattern true for all the endpoints? (Pattern : PrimaryObjects/primaryIdentifier/subObject...), if it is true for current version. Will this pattern change for the later version?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph API follows pattern specified by [OData V4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html) . The pattern goes like "/entitySet/identifier/navigations/identifier". The above link should give details of all patterns involved. The pattern is not expected to change anytime soon and we guarantee to not make breaking changes to public versions (like v1.0) of the API. Also refer to API documentation [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the OpenAPI description that we generated based off the $metadata. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-openapi